# GTK tile editor?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I'm looking for a way of creating a GTK tile/grid editor, something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WetTMC7VHPE

Dos anyone know any ready widget? Maybe a built-in feature?

Comment: Whats the purpose? GIMP supports custom brush, but do you want to use it for a strategy game?

Comment: Take a look at "megaglest_editor" exists in MegaGlest package.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a ready-made widget for that. I would suggest using a canvas widget such as GooCanvas.